# I cant pause and continue CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Hi I am trying to pause and resume my CountDownTimer but it doesn't work, first I get `millisUntilFinished`variable to `futureMins` and in the `onClick()`method of my event listener I set `futureMins` to `mins` i thought after i set these variables to each other  when I call  `countDownTimer.start();` CountDownTimer will start with the last time but it doesnt starts with last time :(

Edit: [I solved problem with using this class](https://github.com/brucemax/AndroidCountDownTimerWithPause/blob/master/CountDownTimerWithPause.java)

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class TimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String output;
    long seconds;


    private long futureMins;
    private long mins = 2401000 ;

    private TextView secText;



    TimeOutReminderService service;

    public boolean onBreak=false;

    Snackbar snackbar;

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer2;

    public TextView minText;


    public Button pauseButton;
    private Button continueButton;
    private Button silenceButton;


    boolean cameFromSilenceButtonClick=false;


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i("INFO","onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i("INFO","onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.ZaaTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.time_activity);

        final View view=findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        pauseButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        minText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.minuteText);
        secText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsText);

        continueButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
        silenceButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.silenceButton);




        snackbar=Snackbar.make(view,"Unutma!   eğer uygulamadan çıkarsan süren sıfırlanır! ",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("Tamam", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();






        countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(mins,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                minText.setText((formatTimeMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
                secText.setText(formatTimeSeconds(millisUntilFinished));
                futureMins=millisUntilFinished;


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                onBreak=true;
                if (onBreak){
                    Log.i("INFO","User in break time  now!");
                }
                service.startService(new Intent(TimeActivity.this,TimeActivity.class));
                quietButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                stopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                countDownTimer2=new CountDownTimer(300000,1000) {


                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        minText.setText(formatTimeMinutes(millisUntilFinished));
                        secText.setText(formatTimeSeconds(millisUntilFinished));


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        service.stopService(new Intent(TimeActivity.this,TimeActivity.class));
                        quietButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                };


            }



        }.start();



        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 futureMins=mins;

            if (cameFromQuietButtonClick){
                countDownTimer2.cancel();
                cameFromQuietButtonClick=false;

            }
            if (cameFromQuietButtonClick==false) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                continueButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                stopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                countDownTimer.start();
                continueButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        silenceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cameFromSilenceButtonClick=true;
                service.stopService(new Intent(TimeActivity.this,TimeActivity.class));
                quietButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });



        }




    public String formatTimeMinutes(long mlSeconds){
        output="";
        seconds=mlSeconds/1000;
        long minutes=seconds/60;


        seconds=seconds%60;
        minutes=minutes%60;




        String minutesD=String.valueOf(minutes);






        if (minutes<10) {
            minutesD = "0" + minutes;
        }





        return minutesD;


    }

    public String formatTimeSeconds(long mlSeconds){
        output="";
        seconds=mlSeconds/1000;



        seconds=seconds%60;




        String secondsD=String.valueOf(seconds);




        if (seconds<10) {
            secondsD = "0" + seconds;
        }




        return secondsD;


    }



    }
```

Comment: might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669379/how-to-implement-pause-and-resume-method-in-countdowntimer

Answer (score 2):

That is because you constructed your timer instance with your original "mins" value. The CountDownTimer class cannot be updated, so in order to update its time you need to construct the CountDownTimer object again this time with the updated value.